# Taylor Big Baby vs Koa Limited Edition Taylor 324ce-k-FLTD

Tags: guitar

What are the differences between an extremely expensive guitar such as the [324ce-K](http://www.taylorguitars.com/guitars/acoustic/324ce-k-fltd) and a very cheap / affordable acoustic like the [Big Baby](http://www.taylorguitars.com/guitars/acoustic/big-baby-taylor)? Could somebody enlighten me as to why one is worth so much more? Specs, wood, playability, electronics, tone, longevity etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many, many reasons for differing price. I'm not going to refer to your two specific guitars in the question, as that makes it far too localised and close-worthy, so instead I'm going for the wider view:

- Wood - some woods are more expensive due to their rarity. Some are more resistant to warping, temperature or humidity changes etc.
- Sustain/Tone - linked to wood, but also construction, tone and sustain are key to how a guitar sounds, and can impact the price dramatically
- Appearance - linked to wood, build quality and finishing. A lacquered book matched burl finish is likely to be a lot more expensive than a painted pine slab of wood
- Electronics - these can have a major effect on the quality of sound. Good quality electronics can cost a lot
- Neck - for playability and tone, a well made neck is worth a lot more than a cheap one
- Setup - the combination of bridge, neck, fretboard, nut and strings affects playability, comfort and tone

At the end of the day, play them - see what one you prefer. Then work out if that is worth the money you are willing to spend.

Answer (score 0):

This goes for all the cheap  vs expensive instruments, not just for acoustic guitars:

- A cheap guitar isn't always a bad guitar. It's just made using cheaper materials. Using lower quality woods, strings and hardware. This equals to lower quality of sound the guitar produces. Note that this doesn't necessarily mean that the sound will be bad. It can be good up to a point, but you won't get any marvelous sounds.
- A cheap wood that is used on a guitar might not be that durable. A good guitar might last many many years, but a cheap one probably won't.
- Usually, cheap guitars get out of tune easier. This means that you'll have to tune it more often, in contrast with an expensive guitar.
- A good guitar is easier to play. I had an old-cheap acoustic guitar and had to press real hard on the strings to play. This isn't the case on expensive guitars.

Answer (score 0):

I own a Baby Taylor and they have crappy tuners. My Epiphone LP has one sharp-edged fret...

In general cheap guitars mean cheap material and no luthier ever touches your guitar while being fabricated. Which also means a cheap guitar's setup mostly is not really good.

But still cheap guitars are the ones you want to buy until being at least an intermediate player...